# Octave Gauss Jordan

Tags: math, matrix, octave

I have been trying to do Gauss jordan method in matrices in octave, and I have found diferent ways to call the function, but none works. How can I do that?

```
A=[1 -2 -1; -1 1 1; 1 1 5]
B=[1; 4; -3]

#format rat

#Transposta = transpose(A)         #Transposta
#Inversa = inv(A)                  #Inversa
#Adjunta = det(A)*inv(A)           #Adjunta se A tiver inversa
determinante = det(A)              #Determinante.
Resultado = Gaussian(A)
```

Comment: What do you mean "different ways"?  Also Gaussian elimination is a loop, so where is your loop?

Comment: Thats my point, my teacher just used a function without the loop. But I can´t find it anywhere.

Comment: He probably wrote the function by himself or found some existing code elsewhere. Apparently there's no buit-in function for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `rref` function...

```
A = [1 -2 -1; -1 1 1; 1 1 5]
B = [1; 4; -3]
C = [A, B]
[a, b] = rref(C)
```

Result

```
a = 1.0000        0        0  -7.1667
         0   1.0000        0  -5.0000
         0        0   1.0000   1.8333
```

More Info: https://docs.octave.org/v7.3.0/Basic-Matrix-Functions.html

Comment: Yeap, thats it. Thanks.